# Error running tensorboard to check model logs

Tags: tensorboard

I have this error when i try to run tensorboard to check the logs of my model.

tensorboard --logdir = 06/logs

RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6

In pycham on OSX. Please help

Comment: You probably mean pycharm?